# Powershell script runs from command line but not from TFS

Tags: powershell-2.0

I have a powershell script that I am trying to run from our build box. When I run it from a dos prompt they run as expected. When the build process calls the same command line it just hangs and I don't see the cause.

The command I am passing to tfs is:

```
powershell.exe  "& 'd:\Builds\37\MyTeamProject\MybuildDefName\Sources\Trunk\Scripts\PowerShell\myScript.ps1' '' "
```

What could I be missing?

Comment: What does the script do? Make sure that the TFSBuildAgent user has enough rights to do what you are doing within your PS script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the major problem was permissions. To verify that I logged in to the server as the tfs build account and corrected the issues.